no Jupyter: Specify Jupyter server for connections
I installed python and jupyter extensions in VS Code, but I don't see "Jupyter: Specify Jupyter server URI" or "Jupyter: Specify Jupyter server for connections" in the command palette.
The only commands related to jupyter and server are "Jupyter: Select Interpreter to Start Jupyter Server" and "Jupyter: Clear Jupyter Remote Server List".
